# Adding two Buttons dynamically in UITableViewCell at last cells after displaying JSON value on each cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a requirement for an IPhone app in which I am processing a JSON string, converting an object from it and then displaying the value from this object to each cell in `UITableView`. JSON string can vary and accordingly no. of cells can all vary.

My requirement is to display two buttons "Accept" and "Declined" in the next two cells after displaying JSON values.

Problem is that I cannot find a way to achieve it.

This is what I have been trying but it does not help:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];if(row==(pathToLastRow.row+1)){
    UIButton *acceptButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    acceptButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 400.0f, 44.0f);
    acceptButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [acceptButton setTitle:@"ACCEPT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:acceptButton];
}
if(row==(pathToLastRow.row+2))
{
    UIButton *declinedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    declinedButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 400.0f, 44.0f);
    declinedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [declinedButton setTitle:@"DECLINED" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:declinedButton];
}    NSString *values = [valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.valueObtained.text = values;
NSString *titles = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.headerInfo.text = titles;

return cell;
}
```

It does not display the button in cell.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Number of rows in section jsonArray.count+2?

Comment: add the subView to cell.contentView instead of directly on cell. The content view might be pushing the added subview back.

Comment: you can add section footer "footerViewForSection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made the code changes as suggested above to get the buttons as footer and could see that it is displayed fine.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [valueArray count];
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    NSString *values = [valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.valueObtained.text = values;


        NSString *titles = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.headerInfo.text = titles;

    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 100.0f;
    }

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *footerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];

        UIButton *rejectButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        rejectButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 30);
        [rejectButton setTitle:@"Reject" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rejectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rejectButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rejectButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        rejectButton.tag = 1;

        UIButton *approveButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        approveButton.frame=CGRectMake(200, 0, 130, 30);
        [approveButton setTitle:@"Approve" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [approveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(approveButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [approveButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [footerView addSubview:rejectButton];
        [footerView addSubview:approveButton];
        return footerView;

}

- (void)rejectButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Reject Button Pressed");
}

- (void)approveButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Approved Button Pressed");
}
```

Thank you all for quick turnaround and provide valuable suggestions to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding those buttons as a table's cell. You can always add them as table's footer or subview of your table's superview (to make them top of the view).

You can configure table's footer using following delegates:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {}`

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {}`

Comment: The requirement is to display those as cell button not as footer. Also @Nikunj it just override the already existing cell value with One button and other button does not display as all.

Comment: Please let me know where I am making mistake. It must be around the row count but I am not able to point it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Change Only this :

```
UIButton *acceptButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 acceptButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 400.0f, 44.0f);
 acceptButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 [acceptButton setTitle:@"ACCEPT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:acceptButton]; // Change Here
```

Comment: Thanks Nikunj.. But it just override the already existing cell value with one button and other button does not display at all.Please let me know where I am making mistake. It must be around the row count but I am not able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add those buttons to table footer view as bellow in viewDidLoad method

UIView *fullView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height)];
    fullView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.tableView.tableFooterView = fullView;

UIButton *acceptButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

```
acceptButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 400.0f, 44.0f);

acceptButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[acceptButton setTitle:@"ACCEPT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[fullView addSubview:acceptButton];
```

UIButton *declinedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

```
declinedButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, acceptButton.frame.size.height+10.0f, 400.0f, 44.0f);
declinedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[declinedButton setTitle:@"DECLINED" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[fullView addSubview:declinedButton];
```